# What is the point of 'no-cors' if you can't read the response?

Tags: javascript, cors, fetch

Self-explanatory. I do not have control over the API and must make a CORS request to the server. I need to parse the HTML response, which I understand is entirely impossible without a proxy.

What is the point of fetch 'no-cors' if you can't read the response? What can be done with it that is of any use?

Comment: you can SEND data

Comment: ^, what you could already do with `<form>`.

Comment: @Ry- FORM can not send arbitrary HTTP headers.